# jsonp referer url determine

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, jsonp

I have a jquery plugin and I'm using jsonp for crossdomain call to a jsp file.
I want to strict the jsp return values only to specific websites in our database. 
To achieve this I need to somehow get the ip or url of the website the jsonp call triggered and not the client/user ip. I've tried the referer value in the http header but this will not work with IE and I guess this is not the best solution either.
How can I securely now who is calling my jsp file with my plugin, from his website?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer would be to issue each website a unique key or other identifier that they include in their request. You parse this identifier and flex your response appropriately.

However with a request originating from the client browser, you would have to be careful and would have to evaluate what you mean by how "securely" you need the request to be handled. (since the untrusted client would be making the request it would be a simple task to harvest and reuse such an identifier)...

Referrer (if present) could be used as a double check, but as you pointed out, this is unreliable and coming from an untrusted client computer, this portion of the request could be faked as well.

If we could assume some server side processing by the website owners, you could have them implement a proxy for the jsonp call (which would ensure such a token would never fall into the hands of the browser)... but we'd have to know if such a safeguard would really be worth it or not :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Charlie. I had the same thoughts and concerns with you on this and I was hoping for a most 'user integrated friendly solution'. You see, I have to make this as a plugin so it can be easily copy pasted in any web site static or not. I was wandering how is google identifying the domain with analytics script ? Can't be only with account key.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Google Analytics just uses the web property id (optionally a domain name specified in javascript as well, and some other client side options)... Google might have algorithms to detect if they suspect someone is trying to game analytics. But I cannot see any value in recording extra click information to someone else's analytics account, so who cares if a browser gets this token ID. (They could not use it for anything other than recording a click so *shrug*) This is possibly different from your scenario (but sans details, I could not say).

Comment: Well, in my case i want to run a survey script so I have to track the website where survey is running, to maintain valid statistics. I can't let anyone that is not in my database to just get the script and run the survey on his website.